# Register Interface in Unity Container based on Marker interface into different Lifetime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, castle-windsor

I have multiple projects in my solution:

```
Core
Repository
Service
WebAPi
```

My Unity registration is on WebAPi Project.

What I am trying to achieve is something I have done in Castle Windsor in the past, now I want to do that via Unity: register interface using convention https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md

I have two  Marker interfaces.

```
public interface ISingletonDependency{}
public interface ITransientDependency{}
```

For classes in my Repository or Service I do:

```
public interface IPersonRepository:ISingletonDependency{
...
...

}

public class PersonRepository: IPersonRepository{
...
...
...
}
```

In my service class:

```
public interface IPersonService:ISingletonDependency{
...
...    
}

public class PersonService: IPersonService{
...
...
...
}
```

I do this for all of my classes in similar way for DI and during registration I used to do:

```
container.Register(
    Classes.NamedAssembly("SolutionName.Repository")
        .BasedOn<ISingletonDependency>()
        .WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleSingleton()
);


container.Register(
    Classes.NamedAssembly("SolutionName.Service")
        .BasedOn<ISingletonDependency>()
        .WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleSingleton()
);


container.Register(
    Classes.NamedAssembly("SolutionName.Repository")
        .BasedOn<ITransientDependency>()
        .WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleTansient()
);


container.Register(
    Classes.NamedAssembly("SolutionName.Service")
        .BasedOn<ITransientDependency>()
        .WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleTansient()
);
```

This way I do not need to do this for each and every one, I saw approach in Unity but it does based on naming convention 
and you cannot specify singleton or transient lifestyle separately.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/agile/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention/

**Is there a way to do what you can do in Castle Windsor, as in the above example I gave, based on marker interfaces?**

Comment: `i have done in Castle windsor in past, now i want to do that via Unity...` - Why are you moving from a fully supported DI container to a *dead* one? Unity is [no longer supported](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues) and even when it was it was seriously far behind in features. Microsoft [gave up support for it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/), but the new owners don't care to support it either - there hasn't been a commit in a year and a half.

Comment: +100 for @NightOwl888's comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
public interface ISingletonDependency { }
public interface ITransientDependency { }

public interface IPersonRepository : ISingletonDependency { }
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository { }

public interface IPersonService : ITransientDependency { }
public class PersonService : IPersonService { }
```

Then you could register the types using:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().Where(
        // Could also match on namespace etc. here
        t => t.Assembly.GetName().Name.StartsWith("SolutionName")),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.FromMarkerInterface);

// Singleton
Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(container.Resolve<IPersonRepository>(), container.Resolve<IPersonRepository>()));

// Transient
Debug.Assert(!ReferenceEquals(container.Resolve<IPersonService>(), container.Resolve<IPersonService>()));
```

`WithLifetime.FromMarkerInterface`  is a custom convention that uses the marker interface to select the correct `LifetimeManager`:

```
public static class WithLifetime
{
    public static LifetimeManager FromMarkerInterface(Type type)
    {
        if (typeof(ISingletonDependency).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            return new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager();
        }

        return new TransientLifetimeManager();
    }
}
```

In this case everything is transient unless it is an `ISingletonDependency` but you could make the rules more explicit (e.g. throw if no valid marker interface is found).

If you could narrow your where clause in `AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().Where` then you could probably get away with a one liner:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().Where(
    t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("SolutionName.Repository") || 
         t.Namespace.StartsWith("SolutionName.Service")),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.FromMarkerInterface);
```